# Uploading a file using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, thymeleaf

I am trying to upload a file to the server using a spring controller.

This is my web config:

```
   @Bean
   public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartConfigElement() {
      CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
      commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
      commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(400000002);
      return commonsMultipartResolver;
   }

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(securityInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
   }

   @Bean
   public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
      TemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".html");
      resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
      return resolver;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver resolver) {
      SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      engine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
      return engine;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine engine) {
      ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      resolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
      return resolver;
   }
```

And this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request)
         throws IOException, ServletException {
      System.out.println("Request: " + request); // REM: Debug Print

      final String path = request.getParameter("destination");
      final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");

      System.out.println("Path: " + path); // REM: Debug Print
      System.out.println("File Part toString: " + filePart); // REM: Debug Print
      if (filePart != null) {
         System.out.println("File Part name: " + filePart.getName()); // REM: Debug Print
         System.out.println("File Part size: " + filePart.getSize()); // REM: Debug Print
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Parts is null"); // REM: Debug Print
      }
      return "file_upload_testing";
   }
```

The class is annotated with `@MultipartConfig`.

I am using Thymeleaf on the front end and I have created a simple form to try get the upload working as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>
            <input type="text" value="/tmp" name="destination"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

All my other controllers are working, I just cannot get the `MultipartFile` into the controller.

I have tried using the `MultipartFile` as a parameter into the my controller and I have also tried casting the `HttpServletRequest` to a Multipart request. None of this made any difference.

When I make the request to the controller with a text file this is the output:

```
Request: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48d0006b
Path: null
File Part toString(): null
Parts is null
```

Please help my figure out why the file is not coming through with the request?

[UPDATE] 
I have tried changing the request mapping to `@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)` but still get the same output.

I have now also tried:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
   System.out.println("File: " + file); // REM: Debug Print
   return "file_upload_testing";
}
```

Web config:

```
   @Bean
   public MultipartResolver mulitpartResolver() {
      CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
      commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
      commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(400000002);
      return commonsMultipartResolver;
   }
```

With this I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
```

Comment: Rename `multipartConfigElement` to `mulitpartResolver` it is a magic name... IF it is named differently it isn't used. Also you are using not the standard servlet file upload but apache commons so there will be no `Part` but a `MultipartFile`. I suggest using springs abstraction which makes those things transparent.

Comment: When you say using spring absractions, do you mean something like: `@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {...}`?

Comment: For instance, or use the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` to obtain the files.

Comment: Just tried that and got `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48844380`

Comment: Well of course if you haven't changed your configuration to reflect the correct name for your `MultipartResolver`.

Comment: I have. The updates at the bottom of the question are all now in place in my code. As well as the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` parameter in the controller method.

Comment: No you haven't you sloppy pasted my comment which contains a typo... The name must be `multipartResolver`. Instead of sloppy pasting I suggest a read of the reference guide and try to understand how it works... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart

Comment: “I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.” - Bill Gates ;) .... Didn't even see that. It is working now! I will check out your link. Thank you **so** much for your help!

Comment: Try to add `@RequestParam("myFile")` annotation as seen in [this example](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Fileupload-sample-for-Thyme-and-Spring-3-td3668412.html).

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a request method problem.

Your controller's request method is `GET` in `uploadFile` method but you want to `POST` a file in html form.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that! Just changed it to POST and got the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was created a long ago, but if anyone's still interested in the question, my solution is to put a name for the resolver bean. Careful about the name, it has to be "multipartResolver", otherwise it probably will not work.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public MultipartResolver mulitpartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(400000002);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```